# Why don't hostnames work in pam_access?

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/access.conf) for `access.conf` specifies using a DNS hostname for the origin field:

```
+ : foo_user : foo1.bar.org
```

but, I get errors in auth.log (Ubuntu 16.04) when connecting over `ssh`. If I change foo1.bar.org to 185.53.177.30 then things work. What have I missed?

```
`pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user 'foo_user' from '185.53.177.30'.
```

Comment: Seems there is no reverse DNS available for `foo1.bar.org`? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-test-or-check-reverse-dns/ Try adding the entry to the /etc/hosts file (`185.53.177.30 foo1.bar.org`) to see if it works then.

Comment: Ok, bad example. I was just using the hostname from the manpage. Is the fact it's missing RDNS actually the culprit here?  The actual host I'm using returns a non-authoritative answer for it's RDNS.  I'd rather just put the hard coded IP in /etc/security/access.conf in that case.

Comment: "The actual host I'm using returns a non-authoritative answer for it's RDNS" - does the one you are trying to log on know whom to ask for the RDNS? Usually, it will not ask the client, but some reliable name server. Otherwise, everyone could fake the FQDN. Try `host 185.53.177.30` command on the target host.

Answer (score 2):

sshd does not lookup hostnames by default so they won't (can't) be passed to pam. Take a look at option "UseDNS" in sshd_config.